# Highcharts - Grouping certain columns in a series together while maintaining proper column widths

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to structure a bar chart's series data such that certain columns can be grouped together while properly maintaining the column widths?

http://jsfiddle.net/fLfctxjj/

```
"series": [
  {
    "name": "Market Value",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Market Value",
        "y": 216264
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Benchmark Market Value",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Market Value",
        "y": 216264
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Notional Market Value",
    "data": [
     {
        "name": "Notional Market Value",
        "y": 216655
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In my example, I want the columns of Market Value and Benchmark Market Value to be grouped WITH proper column widths (dynamically generated without altering pointWidth), and the other column of Notional Market Value to be on the right side with a width equivalent to the left side's grouped columns.

Here, because there are 3 series, the left side has columns #1 & #2 filled and #3 with an empty value and the right side has #1 & #2 empty, and #3 filled.

Comment: How you want your chart to look like, add image

Comment: It would look something like this https://i.imgur.com/oB9yANm.jpg

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/er77smr7/ based on your series data

Answer (score 0):

That look is not currently supported by Highcharts.

The property responsible for positioning columns is `grouping`.

**Workaround:**

If you disable it, all columns that have the same `x` value will be overlaid. The property that allows to alter the position of the point manually is `pointPlacement`. Unfortunately it can be used only on **series** object (not on a single point) so we need to create a separate series for every point.

**Example:**

Data:

```
series: [{
    data: [[0, 3], [1, 5]],
    name: 'Series 1',
    color: 'red'
}, {
    data: [[0, 3], [2, 7]],
    name: 'Series 2',
    color: 'blue'
}]
```

should be changed to:

```
series: [{
    data: [[0, 3]],
    name: 'Series 1',
    color: 'red'
}, {
    data: [[1, 5]],
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: 'red'
}, {
    data: [[0, 3]],
    name: 'Series 2',
    color: 'blue'
}, {
    data: [[2, 7]],
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: 'blue'
}]
```

`linkedTo: ':previous'` will cause that additional unneccesary series won't appear in the legend.

When the data is prepared we need to apply appropriate values of `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` to each series. To compute them we need to iterate all the points and check how many points have the same x value.

Example for `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` values:

```
series: [{
    data: [[0, 3]],
    name: 'Series 1',
    color: 'red',
    pointPlacement: -0.3, // there're two values where x === 0 and this is the first of them - move it to the left
    pointPadding: 0.3 // increase the padding - column is thinner
}, {
    data: [[1, 5]],
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: 'red',
    pointPlacement: 0, // there's only one point where x === 1 - center it
    pointPadding: 0.1 // take almost the whole space available for it
}, {
    data: [[0, 3]],
    name: 'Series 2',
    color: 'blue',
    pointPlacement: 0.3, // there're two values where x === 0 and this is the second of them - move it to the right
    pointPadding: 0.3 // increase the padding - column is thinner
}]
```

As soon as you figure out how `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` work you'll be able to find a generic formula computing them.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPlacement
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo